# Material-UI: DataGrid scrollbar is not rendering

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a `DataGrid` with at least 20 rows. What I wanted is to limit it's display within a certain height and the rest of the rows can be seen using the scrollbar of the component. The scroll for the `DataGrid` itself is not showing

```
<DataGrid
    columns={columns}
    rows={data}
    checkboxSelection
    hideFooter
    autoHeight
    disableSelectionOnClick
    disableColumnMenu
    disableColumnSelector
/>
```

Edit: `pageSize` is not allowed since it has been decided to not use it in the other pages as well, so I have no choice but to use scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I wanted is to limit it's display within a certain height

If you want to set the `DataGrid` height explicitly, you should remove the `autoHeight` props and add a wrapper with a height limit:

```js
<div style={{ height: 300 }}>
  <DataGrid
    columns={columns}
    rows={rows}
    checkboxSelection
    hideFooter
    // autoHeight
    disableSelectionOnClick
    disableColumnMenu
    disableColumnSelector
  />
</div>
```

Bonus point: you can set the `DataGrid` height to display a certain number of rows instead of pixels by installing the `@material-ui/x-grid` and import the default `rowHeight` and `headerHeight`. The code below will display 4 rows in the viewport.

```js
import { DEFAULT_GRID_OPTIONS } from "@material-ui/x-grid";

// ...

const { rowHeight, headerHeight } = DEFAULT_GRID_OPTIONS;

export default function DataGridDemo() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: headerHeight + rowHeight * 4 }}>
      <DataGrid
        columns={columns}
        rows={rows}
        checkboxSelection
        hideFooter
        // autoHeight
        disableSelectionOnClick
        disableColumnMenu
        disableColumnSelector
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67118439/datagrid-scrollbar-is-not-rendering]

Answer (score 0):

Please check could you able to control by

```
<div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting but using pagesize is not allowed since it has been decided to not use it in the other pages as well, so I have no choice but to use scrollbar.

Comment: No.. I have referred the Div tag which has height and width to control your grid.